# Subdivision Surface Being Pulled Toward Vertices

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm working on the torso of a character model, and I added a subdivision surface modifier to get a rough idea of the smoothed final product. Not soon after, I noticed that there were some holes in my geometry, and I quickly filled them. Once the mesh had been fixed, however, there were a few areas where the subdivision surface mod would be pulled to a vertex of the mesh.

The model with subdivision and mesh analysis (sharp). Those red bits are where the subdivision is being pulled.
[image: Picture of mesh with mesh analysis showing the subdivided mesh being pulled to the original]

Better angle with Mirror mod on.
[image: Similar picture to above with a better view of the protrusions]

There don't seem to be any N-gons, and the triangle that was originally there from filling the mesh has been turned into a quad. It is possible that there are some doubled vertices, but I doubt that that's the problem. Recalculating the normals didn't help much either.

I feel it has something to do with me filling faces connected to those points, though I am still unsure of the cause. The Blend file should be below. Help is appreciated.

[Blend File, Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O2rmPcEBEp3OHxOFgkVlqoeFPqaKMlFZ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 faces overlapping, you must have missed it because the vertex is hidden in *Edit* mode, unhide it with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> then delete it:

[image]